# Set git email based on read entry from bash script

Tags: bash, git, ansible

I have a ansible playbook invoking multiple .sh scripts, this one fails as it isn't set properly and it's my first time using read and not sure how to properly use it.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Please set your email address, stuff it up? enter git config    user.email";
read ea;
git config --global user.email $ea;
exit;
```

What I want it to do, as currently it skips this entirely or just errors, is to ask for the user for input to enter their email address and set the git email as that input and continue on the rest of the playbook.
done

Comment: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.6/user_guide/playbooks_prompts.html

Comment: That helps to a certain degree but when I need to execute the command to set the email git config --global user.email "email" that variable isn't set or saved anywhere to call upon

Answer (score 0):

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  become: no
  vars_prompt:
    - name: git_email
      prompt: Please enter your email address for use with git commits
      private: no
  tasks:
  - shell: |
      git config --global core.email "{{ git_email }}"
```

And, according to the fine manual, they can bypass that prompt by running ansible-playbook with `--extra-vars '{"git_email": "bob@example.com"}'`

Comment: This is good, however "git_email" doesn't store what the prompt input was and doesn't output that entry when executed

Comment: I personally executed that code snippet before posting it, including with and without the `extra-vars` bit. Feel free to update your question with the error you are getting and we'll try to work it out

Comment: It prompts nicely, then it prints quite plainly into the terminal "git config --global user.email "{{ git_email }}"" and when checking it with git config user.email comes up with "{{ git_email }}" vars_prompt:
      - name: git_email
        prompt: Please enter your DJR email address.
        private: no
        tasks:
      - shell: | 
          git config --global user.email "{{ git_email }}"

Comment: One will observe I said "update your question", as trying to read textual output in a comment is painful

Comment: The error is the value I enter when prompt appears doesn't get stored anywhere and not in "git_email" so when it actually runs that command to set it, it literally only has those words "git_email"